# npm start only opens on port 3000 when package.json specifies different port

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

I have a react project that has multiple build scripts that work on windows machines but on my mac when I run `npm start` it ignores the package.json and opens on port 3000.

`"start": "set PORT=3050 && cross-env CLIENT_ENV=development craco start",`

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Why don't you just use cross-env for both env vars? If nothing else it's more consistent, and the point of cross-env is to work cross-platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For mac and linux instead of `set` you need to use `export`.

Using `cross-env` is probably your best solution in your case, something like

```
"start": "cross-env PORT=3050 && cross-env CLIENT_ENV=development craco start"
```

Comment: `"start": "export PORT=3050 && cross-env CLIENT_ENV=development craco start"` worked

Comment: Why would you still use `&&`?! `cross-env PORT=3050 CLIENT_ENV=development ...`. @ChristopherMellor that won't work back on Windows, and isn't what this answer suggests (although it's been accepted).

Comment: updated to `cross-env PORT=3050 NODE_ENV=development craco start`